# Open link in Safari from webpage via UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, safari, uiwebview

I have a simple `UIWebView` App where I want to be able to open a specific link on this webpage in Safari.

I've managed to open the Instagram app using this code:

```
<a href="instagram://media?id=4347842891590388200_23134432">Insta</a>
```

I've also managed to open a Safari link via a UIButton with this code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.reddit.com/")!)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how I have an `a href` open in Safari instead of within the `UIWebView` of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a `UIWebViewDelegate` and catch the request in [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) and open the link with `openURL` from `UIApplication`. By checking the navigation type you can also detect if the request was made because the user tapped a link.